# View with a read only column

Tags: sql-server

Hi I would like to design a query where a column is not updateable, but the rest of them yes.

How can I do this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you need to use an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view so that the base table isn't updated directly.

Here is an article explaining them.  [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224818(SQL.80).aspx)

Another example. Sample code shown below.  [Article2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx)

**Sample**
(of course, you need to modify this to fit your view.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Employees_U on Employees FOR UPDATE AS
    IF UPDATE(lastname)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('cannot change lastname', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

Use the trigger to either:

1) error of they try to update that column

2) just don't update that column

Then you should be set.

Comment: Perfect, I will use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know this an OLD question, but I ran across it searching the archives and have (I think) a better solution. Original posters probably don't care at this point, but it may help someone else researching the same problem.

If you define the field in your view that you want to make read-only as the result of some operation, it is automatically not updateable, and this is far less hassle than creating and maintaining a trigger.

In my case, I had a join to an aux table, where I wanted to show the joined field, but not let anyone change it, since it would then change for all joined records, not just the one being edited. The field was a simple text, named Pristup. All I did was define the field in the view as:

LTrim(Pristup) Pristup

This keeps the same name, but the contents cannot be changed, regardless of permissions. Simple, and thoroughly effective.

Comment: There is a good example on StackExchange at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36163/is-it-possible-to-make-one-column-readonly.  
  
This is way better than a trigger. However, the error message you'll get when you try to update the readonly derived fields isn't the best but it's livable.